# Make page responsive using only CSS

Tags: css

I'm working on a project for a payments company and they require the use of an external page in order to collect payment information.

The only modifications that you can make to this page are supplying a custom CSS file.

There is no meta view port tag on the page, if I add one manually to my browser it works exactly how I want it to, however there is no way to add it to their page since it is controlled by a huge payment company not willing to make any changes.

Is there any way around this? I've tried using the @media tag to my css to change zoom based on screen size since that seems to help, but it doesn't take when I add it to my CSS.

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700');


html{
    background-color: #2c3745;
}



.PageBody{margin: auto; margin-top: 10px; border-radius: 5px; background-color: white; padding: 30px; max-width: 600px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;height: auto;min-height: auto;}
.PageContent{ width: auto;color: #000000;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;font-size: 14px; }
.ErrorBackground{ border: 1px solid #C79595 !important;background-color: #FAF2F2 !important; }
.ErrorMessage{ margin-bottom: 10px;border: 1px solid #DB9494; padding: 9px 10px 10px 35px; background-color: #FAF2F2;background-image: url("../images/Error.png"); background-position: 10px 10px;background-repeat: no-repeat;border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px; }
.RequiredField{color: red;font-size: 13px;float: right;margin-left: 5px;}

.FieldSet{border: 0px solid #D3D3D3;padding: 0;margin-bottom: 0;border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;}
.Legend{padding-left: 0;padding-right: 7px;color: #A3A3A3;display: none;}
.Label{ display: inline-block;padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;width: 320px;vertical-align: top; }
.TextBox{width: 100%;height: 38px;border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;padding: 0;font-size: 14px;border-radius: 3px;-moz-border-radius: 3px;-webkit-border-radius: 3px;}
.DropDown{width: 300px;height: 40px;border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;padding: 3px;font-size: 14px;border-radius: 2px;-moz-border-radius: 2px;-webkit-border-radius: 2px;}
.LabelColon{padding-left: 3px;display: none;}
.hppFrame {width: 100%;}
.FieldSetOrder{display: none;}

/* IE8, 9 and 10 Specific Styles */
@media screen\0 {
   .LegendIe{ display: inline-block;position: relative;top: -20px;left: -3px;background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 648px) {

/*  .FieldSet {width: 100%;}*/

  .FieldSetOrder .FormRow {margin: 0;}
.FormRightColumn input {width: 100%!important;}
  .FormLeftColumn {text-align: left!important;line-height: 23px;}

  .Label {width: 100%;}
  .FormRightColumn {width: 97%;}
  .FormRow {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin: 0;
}

.FormExpDateMonthField {width: 144px!important;}
.FormExpDateYearField {
    width: 145px!important;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 649px) {
.FormRightColumn {
    width: 62%;
}

.FormRow {
  width: 100%;
}



.FormRightColumn input {width: 100%!important;}
}

#btnSubmit {
    background-color: #5C9DEC;
    color: white;
    border: none;

}

#btnCancel {
    border: 1px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;

}

.button {
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 90px
}

.PageHeader{}
.PageFooter{}

.FormContainer{}

.FieldSetOrder{}
.LegendOrder{}


.FieldsetCreditCard{}
.LegendCreditCard{}


.FieldsetBillingInfo{}
.LegendBillingInfo{}

.FormRow{margin: 0;width: 100%;}
.FormLeftColumn{width: auto;display: inline-block;white-space: nowrap;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;margin-right: 8px;padding-top: 4px;color: #707070;font-weight: bold;clear: both;display: table;font-size: 13px;margin-bottom: 7px;margin-top: 10px;}
.FormRightColumn{/* display: inline-block; */vertical-align: middle;}

.FormAmount{}
.FormAmountLabel{}
.FormAmountValue{}
.FormAmountField{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.FormInvoice{}
.FormInvoiceLabel{}
.FormInvoiceValue{}
.FormInvoiceField{}

.FormComment1{}
.FormComment1Label{}
.FormComment1Value{}
.FormComment1Field{}

.FormComment2{}
.FormComment2Label{margin-bottom: 7px;}
.FormComment2Value{margin-bottom: 7px;}
.FormComment2Field{}

.FormName{}
.FormNameLabel{}
.FormNameLabel1{color: #BEBEBE;font-weight: normal;font-style: italic;}
.FormNameValue{}
.FormNameField{}

.FormCardNumber{}
.FormCardNumberLabel{}
.FormCardNumberValue{}
.FormCardNumberField{}

.FormExpDate{}
.FormExpDateLabel{}
.FormExpDateValue{}
.FormExpDateMonthField{width: 177px;}
.FormExpDateYearField{width: 178px;}

.FormCvv{}
.FormCvvLabel{}
.FormCvvValue{}
.FormCvvField{ width: 95px; }

.FormDescription{
    display: none;
}
.FormDescriptionLabel{}
.FormDescriptionValue{}
.FormDescriptionField{}

.FormAddress1{}
.FormAddress1Label{}
.FormAddress1Value{}
.FormAddress1Field{}

.FormAddress2{}
.FormAddress2Label{}
.FormAddress2Value{}
.FormAddress2Field{}

.FormCity{}
.FormCityLabel{}
.FormCityValue{}
.FormCityField{}

.FormState{}
.FormStateLabel{}
.FormStateValue{}
.FormStateField{}
.FormStateDropDown{}

.FormZip{}
.FormZipLabel{}
.FormZipValue{}
.FormZipField{ width: 95px; }

.FormCountry{}
.FormCountryLabel{}
.FormCountryValue{}
.FormCountryField{}

.FormBankAccountType{}
.FormBankAccountTypeLabel{}
.FormBankAccountValue{}
.FormRadioButtonField{}

.FormBankAccountNumber{}
.FormBankAccountNumberLabel{}
.BankAccountNumberNumberValue{}
.FormBankAccountNumberField{}

.FormBankRoutingNumber{}
.FormBankRoutingNumberLabel{}
.BankRoutingNumberNumberValue{}
.FormBankRoutingNumberField{}

.AcceptOnlyNumbers{}

.input-validation-error { }
.field-validation-error { display: table }
.field-validation-valid { display: none }
.validation-summary-errors { display: none }
.validation-summary-valid { display: none }
.FormBankAccountValue input[type="radio" i] {
width: 20px !important;
height: 10px;
}

.FormBankAccountValue label {
width: 50%;
float: left;
margin: 5px 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: how will you know in what order the css will be applied ? You can write all the correct rules but if something else appears after your css file, it will overwrite your rules. If you are indeed the last writing the dominant css(highest priority), your media queries and important rules should work.

Answer (score -1):

You have to find the CSS elements which are preventing the page from responding in the vanilla HTML and overwrite them in your CSS file.